# Filter Search-Results in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, filter

I am using the Filter Component from James Fairhurst for my site 
http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/cakephp_filter_component/

Now I am stuck, trying to filter the Search Results.

I am trying to do something like i.e. Amazon does:

On the left of the results page, there are Filters like "Rating at least 3 Stars" or "Pricerange".

How could I implement this?
Any ideas where I should start?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on? The filtering itself or is it just the list of filters? Help us help You.

Comment: Actually it is both.
I don't know where to start, I am trying to extend the filter and don't get it.